# thmtools: Custom Header

Tags: mdframed, amsthm, thmtools

I'm using `amsthm` and `thmtools` to customize theorem-like environments. I want a theorem enviroment that has a header that looks like the following: [image].

I tried to use something like `headformat = {\begin{mdframed}Foo\end{mdframed}}` but I did not compile.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

With `thmtools` this is also easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep, 
  spacebelow=\topsep,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  postheadspace=1em,
  preheadhook={\hrule height0.8pt\vskip1ex},
  postheadhook={\mbox{}\newline\vskip-1.75ex\hrule\vskip1ex\noindent}
]{framed}
\declaretheorem[style=framed,name=Theorem]{theo}
\AtEndEnvironment{theo}{\vskip0.5ex\hrule height0.8pt}

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
\begin{theo}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice, however, that the initial and final rules might be detached from the contents should a page break occur there.

### First version

This is terribly easy with [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) (adjust the settings according to your needs):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{tcbtheorem}{Theorem}{
  breakable,
  boxrule=0.6pt,
  colback=white,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  leftrule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  colframe=black,
  colbacktitle=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  coltitle=black,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
}{the}

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
\begin{tcbtheorem}{the title}{test}
\lipsum[4]
\end{tcbtheorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really want to make the switch to`tcolorbox`.

Comment: @Chris No problem. However, take into account that using just `thmtools` is really difficult (I'd say almost impossible) to guarantee that the initial line won't be detached from the contents should a page break occur between them (I've already tried to do this just with `thmtools` before).

Comment: @Chris please see my updated answer for a version using `thmtools`.